# Java HttpResponse clarification

Tags: java, httpresponse

So Im trynna make an HttpsRequest and so fas so good. The thing is, I'm doing something wrong and I think it could be becasue Im using HttpResponse, but I dont find anything similar for Https. Is there a method that works like that one for https, or u can use it indistinctively and my mistake is somewhere else?

Comment: What error are you having? What question do you have, We don't know what you are doing wrong until you share. Don't forget to share you sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: So I'm a bit crazy and started a stock graphicking(?) project with basically no knowledge about api requests, parsing json from the api, grapihcs, ... So I just wanted to make sure my errors weren't in this Https topic. The code is around 400 lines and the mistake is so general i couldnt tell what part to share, I'll ask as I do haha thx tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you question is whether you need to use different classes for HTTP vs. HTTP**s**, then i dare say no (unless you use a library that requires so), i.e. you only use the plain `HttpResponse` even if you actually did an HTTPS request.

The persieved user mechanics for HTTP and HTTPS are quite the same except for the difference in the protocol part of the URI/URL. The encryption happens mostly transparent but may be tweaked if needed (e.g. what encryption method is used).

You might want to read up on the topic because this is something worthwile understanding.